# Bash rename files removing random string between specific strings

Tags: string, bash, file, rename

I want to rename (within bash) a list of files that begin with a specific string 'foo', continue with a a random string of unspecified length 'random1' and continue with another known string 'bar'. Essentially from  'foo_random1_bar_random2' I want 'foo_bar_random2'. I know how to remove specific strings using sed, but not strings of unknown length between specific strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in foo_*_bar_*
do
    j=$(echo "$i"|sed -e 's/foo_.*_bar_\(.*\)/foo_bar_\1/')
    echo mv "$i" "$j"
done
```

This shows a list of `mv` commands. Once you're happy with the commands, remove the `echo` before `mv` so they will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

Using BASH string replacement:

```
f='foo_random1_bar_random2'
echo "${f/*bar/foo_bar}"
```

PS: As per comments below, if there is underscore before `bar` then better to use:

```
echo "${f/*_bar/foo_bar}"
```

**Output:**

```
foo_bar_random2
```

Use `mv` as:

```
for f in foo_*bar_*; do
   mv -i "$f" "${f/*_bar/foo_bar}"
done
```

Comment: this breaks on foo_random1_bar_randombar2

Comment: I don't see that in the example, OP provided. I will adjust it if there is a possibility like this.

Comment: "random" seems pretty wide input to me ;-)

Comment: It is easily taken care by `"${s/*_bar/foo_bar}"` but OP hasn't specified that underscore will always be there before `bar` as you've also assumed in your answer.

Comment: But that's not the point. The point is that `${f//}` can only do greedy matching for `*`.

Comment: Even sed can only do **only greedy** search.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `rename` tool installed you can do this

```
rename 's/foo_.*_bar/foo_bar/' files
```